# what is /opt/UEZi5lcy service?

Tags: raspbian, linux, malware

I found this strange service inside /etc/rc.local. I have never put it there and it replaced every line that i wrote. What is this service? I noticed it because it uses 5% of my CPU

```
#!/bin/sh -e
/opt/UEZi5lcy
exit 0
```

Comment: No idea.  I suggest you switch off the Pi and re-flash the card.  Anything else strange?

Comment: it uses CPU and i don't why after that i saw this service my raspberry stopped booting. I used a program to do a "backup" of every folder and inside rc.local i found this.

Comment: open /opt/UEZi5lcy with a text editor to see if there is anything recognizable

Comment: Have you had that RPi open to the internet without a firewall and without changing the password for the pi userid from "raspberry"? The pi user has sudo so can compromise anything if attacked from the internet.

Comment: @Dougie - firewall and changing password would have no consequence if you download and install something "from the internet" without knowing what it is :p

Comment: 1) No i can't open the service/process anymore. Raspberry stopped booting and i had to reinstall raspbian i saw this suspicious line when i tried to restore all the files. 2) Yes the raspberry was exposed to internet without firewall but for 1d and the only ports open were the apache ports. (Ssh was disabled)

Comment: There are a number of reports very similar to this in the duplicate (one in the question, several more in answers).

Comment: I'd assume it's malware.  If it's a binary, you can use the 'strings' command to check for any text within the binary (e.g. filenames, hostnames, URL's, etc.).  Looks like malware. I have previously exposed web-servers to Internet traffic with a network sniffer watching all the traffic that hits it.  There is a un-ending number of requests that hit the server attempting to exploit vulnerabilities.